# net core claims to security web.api

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token

I have created a rest web api and want to secure it with a bearer token. Thats fine. 
But I also **want to add extra claims**(officenumber from AAD) regarding to the user profile in azure active directory. First I tried to ask my secureity guy to  add the extra claims thru the ADFS. But he said no. He wants me to call the azure graph api for needed claims. 
But **How can I do this in a API?** 
I don´t have a "login" method. I don´t want a extra database with identity stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/) you can find a sample on how to call Graph API (on behalf of the user) from your API, specifically in [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs) code. Note that it's not mandatory to call Graph on behalf of the user, depending on your needs/scenario, you can call Graph just as the API (app) itself, using the client credential flow (with no user assertion).

Comment: Thanks I looked at your links, but you mean that I need to call graph api to get more claims from AAD. Do I need to call the graph api each request. My senario are just. User do SSO on AAD and then the client webapp(angular2) are registered and allowed to call webapi. Then in the api I want to evaluate the auhorization with the needed requirement and auhorisations policys. And in this process i need some more claims i.e officenumber.

Comment: Well, last time I checked, it was not possible to customize claims in the case of OAuth flow - you can only do that in SAML see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization. But things might have changed. Let see if someone else can help and knows if now you can customize the claims in the case of OAuth/OIDC flows.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is still not able to customize the claims via OAuth/OIDC flows with Azure AD at present.

> Do I need to call the graph api each request.  My senario are just. User do SSO on AAD and then the client webapp(angular2) are registered and allowed to call webapi. Then in the api I want to evaluate the auhorization with the needed requirement and auhorisations policys. And in this process i need some more claims i.e officenumber

No. You could generate the claims after you user sign-in and then combine these info to generate a new JWT token. After that your back end only need to validate the token which contained the customize information which generate by your SPA.